# Android: ListView Filter is not working exactly

Tags: android

I'am listing differnt data from the server. Consider i have 5 different type of data in my list. I want to filter the list based on one data. For that I have written the following code.

```
eventFilter  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.eventFilter);
eventFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }       

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        search_data = s.toString();
    }
});
Button searchbtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);
searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        search = new SearchFilter(context, cts);
        search.getFilter().filter(search_data);
    }
});
```

In the above code just am passing the text value to SearchFilter.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(cFilter==null)
    {
        cFilter=new CustomFilter();
    }
    return cFilter;
}
public class CustomFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (mOriginalValues == null) {
            synchronized (mLock) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<CalEvent>(event);
            }
        }

        if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
            ArrayList<CalEvent> list;
            synchronized (mLock) {
                list = new ArrayList<CalEvent>(mOriginalValues);
            }
            results.values = list;
            results.count = list.size();
        } else {
            String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();


            ArrayList<CalEvent> values;
            synchronized (mLock) {
                values = new ArrayList<CalEvent>(mOriginalValues);
            }

            final int count = values.size();
            final ArrayList<CalEvent> newValues = new ArrayList<CalEvent>();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                CalEvent value=values.get(i);
                EventType type = EventType.getEventType(value.event_type);
                String valueText = type.name.toLowerCase();
                if (valueText.indexOf(prefixString)!=-1) {
                    newValues.add(value);
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, value.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("value.toString",value.toString()); 
                } else {
                    ProjectEventFragment.cts.clear();
                    ProjectEventFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            results.values = newValues;
            results.count = newValues.size();
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Here if am typing some data which is not available in the list then the list should be empty or if available then it should list based on the available data. If the data is not available then i am doing clear and setting to `notifyDataSetChanged`. The list is removing all the data when i type non available data. But again when i type the available data then it is not showing all the data.

I don't know where am doing wrong. Please do correct me.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult for me to get whole idea unless you post complete code here. Possible mistake you might be doing is querying on original dataset, which may be getting cleared when you enter null in search bar. try to store original dataset as temporary dataset and then query temporary dataset instead of original. And when user enter null show original dataset and when something is typed then query on temporary dataset. Have a look at the sample provided below, this should help.

```
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence query) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<Notification> resultList = new ArrayList<Notification>();
                ArrayList<TagUser> receivingUsers = new ArrayList<TagUser>();

                if (query == null || query.length() == 0) {
                    results.values = tempNotifcationList;
                    results.count = tempNotifcationList.size();

                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < tempNotifcationList.size(); i++) {
                        String sendingUser = tempNotifcationList.get(i).getTag().getSendingUser().getDisplayName();
                        String message = tempNotifcationList.get(i).getTag().getMessage();
                        if (sendingUser != null) {
                            if (sendingUser.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                                resultList.add(tempNotifcationList.get(i));
                                continue;
                            }

                        }
                        for (String key : tempNotifcationList.get(i).getTag().getReceivingUsers().keySet()) {
                            receivingUsers.add(tempNotifcationList.get(i).getTag().getReceivingUsers().get(key));
                        }
                        if (receivingUsers != null && receivingUsers.size() > 0) {
                            for (TagUser taguser : receivingUsers) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Receiving User:" + taguser.getDisplayName());
                                if (taguser.getDisplayName().toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Receiving User:" + taguser.getDisplayName());
                                    resultList.add(tempNotifcationList.get(i));

                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            continue;

                        }
                        if (message != null) {
                            if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                                resultList.add(tempNotifcationList.get(i));
                                continue;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Done Searching");

                    results.values = resultList;
                    results.count = resultList.size();

                }

                Log.d(TAG, "result set count:" + results.count);
                return results;
            }
```